# Find the best set of weights to maximize sum

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, optimization

I'm struggling with this constrained optimization problem.

Imagine an animal has to decide where it wants to be, and for how much of its time. Assume we are talking about relative usage, so its time sum to 1. Each location has a cost associated to it and the animal wants to minimize that cost. Formally:

$$ {argmin}_{P(x)} \; TC = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(x)C(x) dx $$

where $P(x)$ is the animal distribution and $C(x)$ is the cost distribution. For simplicity we can start with $C(x) = x^2$. $P(x)$ is subjected to the same constrains of a probability distribution $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(x) =1$, $0 \le P(x) \le 1 \:\forall x  $. How can I find $P(x)$ or at least the set of conditions a distribution must satisfy to be considered for $P(x)$.

The best I could do so far was to use the law of the unconscious statistician to learn that TC = $E[C(x)]$. If the $C(x)$ is a linear transformation of $x$ that allows me to calculate the expected value of $P(x)$. But this linearity constrain is very limiting, and not even include the example above.

I tried to use the lagrangrian multiplier technique to no avail. One of the key issues is that the solution fo this intergral seems "inderterminate". Using intergration by parts:

$$ \int P(x)C(x)dx = C(x) \int P(x) dx- \int C^\prime(x)\int P(x) dx dx $$

which translates to:

$$ \int P(x)C(x)dx = C(x)-C(x)+const = const  $$

What am I doing wrong? How can I learn about $P(x)$?

Comment: I am assuming that you will eventually discretise this to solve it. Then you have $\min_p c^Tp, \, p \in [0,1]^n, \, 1^T p = 1$. Then you can just find the index such that  $c_i$ is the smallest and set $p_i = 1$ and $p_j = 0$ everywhere else. In the continuous case that would correspond to choosing a Dirac delta $p(x) = \delta(x-x_{\min})$ centered at the minimum $x_{\min} \in \arg\min_x C(x)$ of $C$. Then the expectation is just $\min_x C(x)$. E.g. if there is a cost of zero somewhere, then the animal will spend its whole time there.

Comment: Indeed, I arrived to the same intuitive solution. But how can you deduce that mathematically? Meaning if I had ${min}_p c^Tp$ how can I prove that the algorithm " find the index such that ci is the smallest and set pi=1 and pj=0 everywhere else" is the one that minimizes it. I'm asking because I would like to arrive to a general rule that could work even if $C(x)$ is bimodal, or multimodal. And when its bimodal the rule seems to change (stay whole time in peak 1 or stay whole time in peak 2 or stay 50 %-50%).

Comment: I think  found the answer to this question. Using @lightxbulb tip of thinking of the process in a discrete way, I found a formal way to express this algorithm [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696061/maximum-and-minimum-of-weighted-sum).It still does not show the logic for bimodal or multimodal distribution but it is a beginning.

Comment: If the global minimum is not unique then you can distribute $p$ as you wish over it. E.g. assume $c_{i_1}, \ldots, c_{i_n}$ are all the global minima. Then any $p$ that is zero everywhere except those is admissible, since $\sum_j c_{i_j} p_{i_j} = c_{\min}\sum_j p_{i_j} = c_{\min}$. In the continuous case you have be more careful with the measure, but essentially it boils down to integration over the set of minimizers. As for the proof, it's just $c_{\min} \leq c_i$ then for any convex linear combination it holds that $c_{\min} = \sum_i \alpha_i c_{\min} \leq \sum_i \alpha_i c_i$.